# Display folders first in File Explorer search

Tags: windows-10, windows-explorer, sorting, windows-search, file-search

Whenever I search for something (in this case "*") in File Explorer, folders appear mixed in with files:
[image]

Is there a way to make it display all folders at the top like it does outside of search?

I've tried sorting by different fields and Shift+Left-clicking on a field but the folders still appear mixed in with files.

Comment: Click on the "Type" column header?

Comment: But then e.g. JPEG files are separate from PNG files. Also, how would I then sort by Name or Date? As is, they appear to be in a random order which isn't very useful.

Comment: Add the `Kind` column to a `Details` view, then play with grouping or sorting on that. Bonus tip: Explorer can sort not only on a primary property (click the column header) and a secondary property (<Shift>+<LeftClick> column header), but successive <Shift>+<LeftClick>'ing on other column headers can select a tertiary and quaternary property as well.

Comment: @KeithMiller As far as I can tell, there is no "File" kind (despite the "Folder" existing.. sigh Microsoft), meaning pictures, videos, text files are all grouped separately.

Comment: That's true, but `KInd` categories are broader than individual types, so `jpg` and `png` aren't separated... :D.  Are you that frequently unsure of whether you are searcing for a file or folder??? If you know which of thoose you're searching for, you can add either `kind:Folder` or `kind:NOT Folder` to your search parameters depending on your needs...

Comment: Also, `Libraries` are essentially saved searches that maintain the "folders before files` convention. Right-clcik in the background of a `Library` and explore the `Arrange by >` options -- which vary based on the LIbrary type...

Comment: @KeithMiller `kind:NOT Folder` - that's it. Thanks matey! To answer your question, no, I am actually never unsure. Guess this was a case of the XY problem.

Comment: `Library` meaning the predefined stuff like Documents, Pictures, Videos etc? Is Downloads considered a library? Because there is no arrange by option upon a right click.

Comment: There are pre-defined folder locations, i.e. `%UserProfile%\Documnets`; pre-defined namespace junctions/shortcuts, i.e. `This PC\Documents`;  and *true* `Libraries`, contained in the `Libraries` folder available in the Navigation Pane, i.e. `shell:Libraries\Documents.library-ms` (not the normal way you would access it, but works in Address bar). I'm speaking of the these, which can reference the contents of multiple locations simultaneouslly and offer unique views of the contents via the `Arrange by >` options I mentioned earlier...